# How to do a filtered select-option-like drop down in Android forms?

Tags: java, android, xml, angular

My situation is: With my AsyncTask class running, i will do a GET request and retrieve a JSONArray from my server and then this is "binded" onto a drop-down/select-option/listView which appears HORIZONTALLY. The user will then have an EditText where he will type and this will filter the list displaying the elements which contain the users entry.
I have worked with this scenerio with Angular JS and this worked perfectly with ng-model,ng-repeat and filters.. etc 
I am trying to convert my webApp to Android. I'm new to android and i would like to have a step by step tutorial to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you a simple way cause you are new in android! add this function to your listView adapter:

```
public void filterList(String searchText)
{
    ArrayList<C_ChatListItem> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    adapteritems = backupItems; // copy your Get response in backupItems for new searches in constructor
                                // then in every new search retrieve adapterIems
    if(searchText != null && searchText.length() > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < adapteritems.size() ; i++)
        {
            if(adapteritems.get(i).users_entry.contains(searchText))
                temp.add(item);
        }
        adapteritems = temp;
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And in your activity add a textWatcher to your search editText like this:

```
et_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            String txt = et_search.getText().toString();
            adapter.filterList(txt);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: *I suggest you a simple and tricky way* -> The concepts of *simple* and tricky are opposed, so your sentence makes very little sense. Apart from this consideration, I would recommend comments in your answers which are not directly related to the answer itself.